# web.xml - user login and session/Google App Engine, GWT

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, authentication, web.xml

How can I achieve such functionality in java ee (servlets, web.xml):

In database there are user credentials (username and password). All users that like to access my service should be prompted to login. When session expires user should be logged out and see login page again. All resources under my WEB-INF should be protected.

I read about [user roles and realms](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbxj.html), but this is not what I need. It limits users to defined in application container.
I'd like to provide my users functionality to register and login.

How can this be achieved in java ee? Can this be done by configuring web.xml ?
I tried servlet mapping on /* and authentication in servler (redirect to login page in case of session expiration) but it didn't worked for my static content (i.e. index.html)

Examples appreciated. Thanks for all answers.

***Using google app engine and gwt.***

Comment: A very important fact left unattented by the OP is that he's using GAE/GWT (as mentioned in a comment on my deleted answer).

Comment: Sorry, thought there is a generic mechanism

Answer (score 0):

You can use container based authentication like JDBCRealm for login/logout functionality but   you have to implement the register functionality yourself. A simple CRUD-application for your user and group table in the database should be a good starting point.

If you use JSF, Tutorials for creating CRUD applications with JSF can be found [here for Netbeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-crud.html).